# Bash or cmd append Java standard out to text file

Tags: bash, cmd, stdout

This is not a question about Java source code. This is a question about appending the result of running a Java program from command line with bash or cmd and *appending* its standard output to a text file.

It is possible to redirect the standard output to a text file. This is destructive and overwrites any previous file with the same name.

```
java HelloWorld > hello.txt
```

**Is it possible to append the final result so that the contents of `hello.txt` are not overwritten every time the program is run?**

I looked in `man java` and did not see anything there about appending.

Comment: Use `>>` instead of `>`

Comment: This is determined by your shell. `>` and `>>` is not recognised by java.

Comment: Thanks guys - the duplicate question by khelwood has the answer.